# How do I properly update an NHibernate Many-to-Many relationship with Transient objects? TransientObjectException

Tags: c#, nhibernate, many-to-many, transient

I am getting a TransientObjectException when attempting to save an object that is part of a many-to-many association.  I somewhat understand why this is happening, but want to understand how to properly accomplish what I am trying to do.

**What I am trying to do, in a nutshell:**

My application has a list of users and a list of roles.  Users can be assigned to multiple roles, and roles can be assigned to multiple users.  There is a web page where an admin can perform these assignments, and the assignments can be done in both directions (e.g., the admin can pick a user, then add roles to it; OR, pick a role and add users to it).

For example, let's say the admin clicks "Edit" on user "Alice."  The admin is presented with a list of roles available and a list of roles already assigned to Alice.  The admin then assigns a new role to Alice and clicks "Save."

On the server, the transient User and assigned Role objects are received from the client.  If I just assign the transient Role list to the User object (e.g., `user.Roles = roles`), I can update just fine.  However, if I happen to read the User from the database before making this assignment, I get a TransientObjectException on the associated Role object.

**Class definitions:**

```
public class Role
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

**Mapping:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="Role">
    <id name="ID">
      <generator class="guid"/>
    </id>

    <bag name="Users" table="Role_User" lazy="false" cascade="none">
      <key column="RoleID" />
      <many-to-many column="UserID" class="User" />
    </bag>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="User">
    <id name="ID">
      <generator class="guid"/>
    </id>

    <bag name="Roles" table="Role_User" lazy="false" cascade="none">
      <key column="UserID" />
      <many-to-many column="RoleID" class="Role" />
    </bag>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Code to save (works)**

```
public void UpdateUser(User user, IList<Role> associatedRoles)
{
    using (var session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession())
    {
        user.Roles = associatedRoles;
        session.Merge<User>(user);
    }
}
```

**Code to save (fails)**

```
public void UpdateUser(User user, IList<Role> associatedRoles)
{
    using (var session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession())
    {
        User originalUser = session.Get<User>(user.ID);
        // Code that does some audit reporting/logging
        LogDifferences(originalUser, user);
        user.Roles = associatedRoles;
        session.Merge<User>(user);
    }
}
```

object is an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before merging

Comment: I think the problem is that your session would have two user instances with the same ID. Try to remove the originalUser from the session with session.Evict().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Miroslav Popovic's points are highly relevant; however, in my case I was running into problems because of entities in the database which had a Version set to an empty guid.  These records were created outside of NHibernate.  When saving an association between them, NHibernate was failing because it detected one of the association entries as a transient object due to its 0 version, even though it referred to an existing item.

Answer (score 1):

Jouni Aro is right... you can't have two instances of the entity with the same ID in your session.

The problem is one of the following:

1. you are trying to load `originalUser` from the DB, but the `user` is already attached to the same session
2. you have loaded the `originalUser`, and after that tried to Merge `user` to the same session - Evict originalUser first, as Jouni suggested

Anyway, do you really need to load original user just to find out what the changes are? There are other ways to do that with NHibernate. Have you tried [interceptors](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#objectstate-interceptors)?

Here's one potential usage: http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/finding-dirty-properties-in-nhibernate.aspx. [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=nhibernate%20interceptors) a bit for more.

Comment: I figured as much, this is one of my main annoyances with NHibernate - if it can detect that there is a transient instance conflicting with a non-transient instance, why not just perform the eviction automatically?  I'm not sure how an interceptor would work here, as this is after a round trip from the client back to the server - the server has no context on individual changed values without doing some kind of comparison (as in the code above).

Comment: The actual code doesn't deal with sessions directly (it is abstracted away), so I may tackle this a different, but similar way.  Instead of evicting the object from the session, I will load it in a parallel session, perform the diff, then close the parallel session.

Comment: I think you are experiencing case #2. Trying to merge user to the same session that already has non-transient originalUser. If NHibernate did some automatic eviction, your originalUser would be kicked out and user would be merged. It might work in your case, but it would probably cause some subtle, hard to track/debug errors in other people code.

Comment: It doesn't matter that your session is abstracted (that's a plus). You would inject custom Interceptor using NHibernate's Configuration object. Within this new Save interceptor you could handle just the User entities that are modified and logging your difference. Save Interceptor kicks in at the very low level... just before changes are persisted to database.

Comment: Meaning that the interceptor would do the above action (e.g., load the original, perform the auditing, evict, then save)?  I might try that.

Comment: Not really... You could just do Merge/Save of the user in your UpdateUser method and Interceptor will catch it before persisted to database. Within interceptor, you will have access to the old (persisted) values for properties so you could compare. No need to load originalUser from database, since the session already holds its state.

Comment: I'm starting to think my issue is more fundamental.  I removed the auditing code completely to test a basic scenario - and it fails with the same error.  My scenario is now a transient object (Role) with an associated transient object (User).  Saving or merging the Role fails.  Cascade is none (default), beacause I never update the associated object - I just want to update the association itself.  Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried to use cascade="save-update" instead of "none"? I think it refers to the association itself in many-to-many scenario. Here's the explanation of cascade options by Ayende: http://ayende.com/blog/1890/nhibernate-cascades-the-different-between-all-all-delete-orphans-and-save-update

Comment: I think I have finally gotten to the bottom of this - it was always failing for entities which had a version of 0 in the database (some initial data is created outside of NHibernate with a script, and the version was set to an empty guid).  Changing the guid to something non-zero elminiates the error